# Warning when reading non-generic HashMap from InputStream

Tags: java, generics, android-studio, casting

I have an instance variable `HashMap<String, Object> sessions;`

I am trying to read a saved instance of `HashMap<String, Object>` from an input stream:

```
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
sessions = (HashMap<String, Object>) is.readObject();
```

However on the second line I'm getting the following warning:

`Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 'java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>'`

It offers me to generify the class, which does exactly nothing. I try to change the instance variable to a raw, generic `HashMap` and also cast to a raw `HashMap` accordingly, but then I'm getting non-checked warning whenever I try to put anything to the hashmap, e.g.:

`sessions.put("all", new ArrayList());`

Yields warning `Unchecked call to 'put(K, V)' as a member of raw type 'java.util.HashMap'`.

I know that these are just warning, and wouldn't create a problem at runtime, but for correctness' sake, how can I get rid of all the warnings?

I am on Android Studio 2.0b7.

Comment: You could read absolutely anything from an `ObjectInputStream` - you will always get an unchecked cast if you attempt to cast the read object to anything other than `Object`. The only way to get rid of the first warning is to add a @SuppressWarnings.

Comment: And don't use the raw type approach.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, I'd like to avoid raw as much as possible, that's why I was trying to get rid of the warning and make sure everything is "strong". As you and Mikhail suggested, adding `@SuppressWarnings` solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way for the compiler to know what type you will read from a `ObjectInputStream` at runtime, so you will always get an unchecked cast warning if you try to explicitly cast it.

The only solution is to add @SuppressWarnings. It is best to add a local variable specifically for the unchecked cast, since you can annotate just this, and not the entire method or class.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
HashMap<String, Object> tmp = (HashMap<String, Object>) input.readObject();
sessions = tmp;
```

However, you should also check that the object you read `instanceof HashMap`, to ensure that unchecked cast is at least partially safe (partially, since you don't know if the values and keys really are the types you'd expect - to be really sure you could iterate the keys to ensure they are all strings).

Answer (score 1):

Just add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation to the line of code. It's possible to add this annotation to a method or a class.

Answer (score 1):

Generic type information is not serialized, as it's removed in the run time by [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

**You can't get exact generic object after de-serialization.** As variable level generic information exists only at compile time.

If it were possible `ObjectInputStream` would provide a way of passing type of the object, which it doesn't.

Type information is accessible only for the `Generic Class Types`. Using this hack [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/expression/spel/ast/TypeReference.html) and [Jackson](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html) provide a way to pass type to read from the stream.

You can write a utility class for custom implementation of `readObject` which receives the type (using Spring or Jackson TypeReference or may be your own simpler implemenation). There you would be able to check if the read object is the correct type if it is then using the passed type it can be cast to correct type. This way you would have to suppress warning at one place and you will be sure that the object being read is of correct type.